# GRUB partition accidentially formatted on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, grub

I am facing a case that the the 1MB GRUB partition on an Ubuntu 18.04 server has been accidentially formatted. The server has not been restarted yet.

Upon running `sudo update-grub` the following errors occur:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50-curtin-settings.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdd2.  Check your device.map.
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdd2.  Check your device.map.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-74-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-74-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdd2.  Check your device.map.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdd2.  Check your device.map.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdd2.  Check your device.map.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-72-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-72-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdd2.  Check your device.map.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdd2.  Check your device.map.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-54-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-54-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdd2.  Check your device.map.
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdd2.  Check your device.map.
done
```

How can I safely repair grub partition without having to reboot the server first?

Comment: What do `grub-install /dev/<your disk name>` give you?

Comment: `grub-install: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdd2. Check your device.map.` although I have done `grub-mkdevicemap`.

Comment: Can you add `/boot/grub/device.map` to your question? The disk you want to install Grub on is in the file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anyway to retrieve the boot part without rebooting.

Insert the installation disk/ USB and search for Ubuntu Repair option.